# Glide - Load a GIF as a placeholder

Tags: android, image, gif, android-glide

I'm using `Glide` in my Android project, and I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of `CardView`s in it. What I wanna do is to load an image for each `CardView` while showing a `GIF` loading image until the real image gets loaded. Now if it try to load the `GIF` as the main image, no problem:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(R.raw.gif_loading_bar)
        .into(imageView);
```

The code above works fine and the `GIF` gets loaded. But when I try to load another image and make the `GIF` a placeholder `Android Studio` shows an error **"Expected resource of type drawable"**:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.raw.gif_loading_bar))
        .load(imageUrl)
        .into(imageView);
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glide does support **GIF** as placeholder. I recently faced this situation and solved it like below. Hope it helps someone like me who is facing this situtaion.

```
    var builder = Glide.with(mContext).load(path).apply(options).thumbnail(Glide.with(mContext).load(R.raw.loader2))
if (listener == null) {
    builder = builder.addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

            //TODO; your code here
            return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            //TODO; your code here
            return false
        }
    })
} else {
    builder = builder.addListener(listener)
}
builder.into(myImageView)
```

> What it does

It load your gif as thumbnail until the image is downloaded from the source.
Inside the **onResourceReady** method it will give you the callback when the resource is ready. Make sure to put  **gif file under R.raw** package and **not in drawable** package. Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `Glide` does not support `GIF` placeholders, as mentioned in [this Github issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1642), and [this one](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/659).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new 
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);

Glide.with(context)
    .asGif()
    .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.raw.gif_loading_bar))
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(imageView);
```

More info [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#picking-a-resource-type) and [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html#glidetype)

Comment: The image gets loaded, but it doesn't move, it's like any static `JPG` or `PNG` image.

Comment: add fix in answer

Comment: `Android Studio` can't find a class with the name `GlideDrawableImageViewTarget`.

Comment: what version of Glide you are using? Try DrawableImageViewTarget insted of GlideDrawableImageViewTarget

Comment: I'm using version `4.8.0`.

Comment: hmm, should work.. Follow 2nd link, use configuration through GlideApp

Comment: It actually turned out that `Glide` does not support `GIF` placeholders. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to change the `getContext()` as per your codes. For example in my case I am passing it as `holder.img.getContext()`

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(item[position])
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.gif_image))
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(imageView);
```